# how to change the array elements and get new array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to modify the array that contains the path in  javascript

how to change the path as shown in expected output

```
var arr =[
  "C:\Users\dc\public\index.js",
  "C:\Users\dc\public\javascripts\index1.js",
  "C:\Users\dc\public\javascripts\index2.js"
]

Expected Output
[
   "/dc/public/index.js",
  "/dc/public/javascripts/index1.js",
  "/dc/public/javascripts/index2.js",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If editing the file paths is not an option, you can use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to accomplish this without having to escape the file paths. Instead of setting the array directly below, I used "push" so that you can use a loop on your own if you get these paths automatically.

```
var arr = [];

arr.push(String.raw `C:\Users\dc\public\index.js`);
arr.push(String.raw `C:\Users\dc\public\javascripts\index1.js`);
arr.push(String.raw `C:\Users\dc\public\javascripts\index2.js`);

arr = arr.map(a => a.replace("C:\\Users", "").replace(/\\/g, "/"));


// Output
console.log(arr);

//0: "/dc/public/index.js"
//1: "/dc/public/javascripts/index1.js"
//2: "/dc/public/javascripts/index2.js"
```

Comment: the drive path may vary `C:\\Users`, is there any way like to show by skipping the first two path name and only show the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =[
    "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\index.js",
    "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js",
    "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js"
];

const outputArr = arr.map(item => {
  const splitArr = item.split("\\");
  const filterArr = splitArr.slice(2, splitArr.length);
  return `\\${filterArr.join("\\")}`;
});

console.log(outputArr);
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does for the user having an issue so they can learn? Also the console just logs items like "dcpublicjavascriptsindex2.js" which is without slashes

Comment: edited my answer, in javascript "\" has a special meaning

Comment: the drive path may vary C:\\Users, is there any way like to show by skipping the first two path name and only show the rest

Answer (score 0):

First replace the prefix "C:\Users" with empty string to delete them. Then replace the "" character in the resulting string with required "/"

```
var arr =[
  "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\index.js",
  "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js",
  "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js"
];

var pattern = new RegExp("(.+)dc")
arr = arr.map(a => a.replace(pattern, "dc").replace("/\\/g", "\/"));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: the drive path may vary C:\\Users, is there any way like to show by skipping the first two path name and only show the rest

Comment: Then we need to put a regex in there to replace everything before \dc\

Comment: @ved check the answer now. I updated it from regex. It will delete everything before the first occurrence of prefix "dc". You can always update the regex pattern as per your needs